# How to make a connect4 board with rounded corners and curved sides?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a connect4 board with exact styles and properties given. Its looks like(Ignore the pieces it is filled with).

[image]

How to make the sides curved from sides like in the image? Please try to use HTML elements only to solve this. If any easy SVG please give that

Currently my code looks like

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) { 
    document.getElementById("cont").appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cont {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 80px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 80px);
    background-color: #84A4FC;
    width: fit-content;
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#cont div {
    background-color: white;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 6px #00000040;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;

}
```

```html
<div id="cont"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approximate this using an SVG filter (more detail here: https://dev.to/afif/css-shapes-with-rounded-corners-56h)

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
  document.getElementById("cont").appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 80px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 80px);
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  /* we need a background to cover only the middle part not the whole element*/
  background:linear-gradient(#84A4FC 0 0) center/calc(100% - 40px) calc(100% - 40px) no-repeat;
  filter:url(#round); /* this */
}

#cont div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0px 3px 6px #00000040,
    0 0 0 10px #84A4FC; /* added this */
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont"></div>

<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="round">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```